# ES6, get all destructing parameters in function as one object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create an object from destructing parameters of my function

```js
const myFunc = ({foo,bar,baz},something,{x,y,z}) =>{
  console.log(someObjectThatContainsFooBarBaz); // {foor,bar,baz}
  console.log(someObjectThatContainsXYZ); // {x,y,z}
}
```

I've tried `({foo,bar,baz}=props)=>...` and `({foo,bar,baz}:props)=>...` already, but none of these works.

Can someone tell me what should I do about this?

Comment: can't you just take everything as parameter, and destructure the object as first line?..

Comment: No cause I'm looking for the best solution not only fixing my code :-) but thanks @Berto99

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another step for creating a new object.

This is not possible to destructure an object and at the same time create a new one with the destructured variables.

```
const myFunc = ({ foo, bar, baz }, something, { x, y, z }) => {
    console.log({ foo, bar, baz }); // new object
    console.log({ x, y, z });       // new object
}
```